# How to create completion for `git flow feature checkout` alias?

Tags: git, git-flow, git-completion

I have configured my `.bash_aliases` like:

```
alias gc="git checkout"
alias gcf="git flow feature checkout"
source ~/.git-completion.bash
__git_complete gc  _git_checkout
source ~/.git-flow-completion.bash
__git_complete gcf __git_flow_feature
```

But when I try to complete I should select `checkout` and then I may select my branch:

```
$ gcf 
checkout   diff       help       publish    rebase     track      
delete     finish     list       pull       start      

$ gcf checkout a
a_branch1 a_branch2
```

What should I do that `checkout` will be selected automatically when I write `gcf`+a<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: `gcf checkout` doesn't make sense as it expands to `git flow feature checkout checkout`

Comment: @Leon I know and I do not want that behaviour

Answer (score 3):

I think one solution might lie with [custom Git alias completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L26-L30):

> If you use complex aliases of form `!f() { ... }; f`, you can use the null
>   command `:` as the first command in the function body to declare the desired
>   completion style.  For example `!f() { : git commit ; ... }; f` will
>   tell the completion to use commit completion.  This also works with aliases
>   of form `!sh -c '...'`.  For example, `!sh -c ': git commit ; ... '`.

So you'll first need to set up a Git alias in your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  ffc = "!ffc() { : git checkout ; git flow feature checkout $@ ; } && ffc"
```

and then link it in `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias gcf="git ffc"
```

It's untested but I think it'll do what you want. You might have some trouble with spacing in the `$@` in the `ffc` alias that `\"$@\"` might fix depending on use case.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L20-L24) - I think this only works after you source `git-completion.bash`, which is probably best to do in your `bashrc`. LMK if that fixes it for you and if it does I'll edit the answer with it.

Comment: As I have mention in my question: `source ~/.git-completion.bash` is aready in by `~/.bashrc`. I need something like `__git_complete gcf __git_flow_feature_XXXXX`. and I can not find `XXXXX`

Comment: although your answer do not resolve my problem I reward you for your try ;-)

Comment: Huh. In that case I'm not really sure how to fix your issue... for your reference, [here's a Git alias that uses __git_complete](https://github.com/sxlijin/.dotfiles/blob/master/git/config#L37).